# How to open and edit a file with .pas format which can be opened by Text editor or Notepad++ in Python?

Tags: python, text-editor

I would like to open a .pas file in Python, ( Generally, I can open the .pas by Text Editor to see what is inside). So, I am looking for the code to open and edit the file in Python.
To more clear, I would like to edit some variables in the file. So first I need to open it and then edit the file.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to show some effort.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Recommended reading: [Question Effort - What's our line in the sand?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388588/10871073)

Comment: @AdrianMole Have you noticed the effort put in the post you linked to, and the length of the answers? The post didn't say "Close questions with no effort?" with an answer "Yep". That says it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the builtin `open()` function to open a text file:

```py
with open('file.pas', mode='r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)